# stop slideshow and load another content, fade it out and play slideshow further

Tags: jquery, ajax, slideshow

I would like to stop my slideshow after each 5. loaded element, fade out the container with the slideshow, load another content element, this will disappear in few minutes and then the container with the slideshow appear again and goes on from the stop point.

My code seems like this at the moment (I use jQuery).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*
    $('.presentation_list').click(function () {
           location.reload(true); 
       });    // RELOAD PAGE ON BUTTON CLICK EVENT.
*/

// SET AUTOMATIC PAGE RELOAD TIME TO 5000 MILISECONDS (5 SECONDS).
      setInterval('refreshPage()', 3600000);

function textShort() {
if ($('#presentation .info').length > 0) {
   var showChar = 160;
   var ellipsestext = "...";
   // var moretext = "more";
   // var lesstext = "less";
   $('.info').each(function() {
       var content = $(this).html();

       if(content.length > showChar) {

           var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
           var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

           var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '</span>';

           $(this).html(html);
       }

   });
}

}
var url = '';
var num = 0;

if ($('#inhalt .tx-ppamthowitrollhusv2-pi1 .presentation_list').length > 0) {
   $('#inhalt .tx-ppamthowitrollhusv2-pi1').append('<div id="presentation"></div>');


   setInterval(function(){
           url = $('#inhalt .tx-ppamthowitrollhusv2-pi1 .presentation_list a').eq(num).attr('href');

       $('#presentation').load(url + ' #inhalt', textShort);
       $('#presentation #inhalt').fadeOut().delay(5000).fadeIn(2000);
       num++;
       return ($liste.length = 5);
            if ($('#inhalt .tx-ppamthowitrollhusv2-pi1 .presentation_list a').each(function() {
            $.length = 5;
            $('.container').fadeOut;
            $('#bild').fadeIn(2000).delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);
            $('.container').fadeIn;

            } 
            )); 

               if (num == $('#inhalt .tx-ppamthowitrollhusv2-pi1 .presentation_list a').length) {
           num = 0;
       }
   }, 8000);
}
});
function refreshPage() { location.reload(); }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a JSfiddle example so we can test what you currently have?

Comment: You can find it on http://www.trollhus.de/index.php?53 I have changed the code a little bit. You can find it on the website above.